# Flycheck installation to aquamacs from melpa failing

Tags: flycheck, aquamacs

Using Aquamacs

> Aquamacs 3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2
>   (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14)
>    of 2014-11-07 (Aquamacs-3.2) on watson.local

trying to install Flycheck from stable.melpa.org; I get this message

> https://stable.melpa.org/packages/flycheck-20160519.303.tar: Not found

I've tried using package-mode, and also the temporary install method (eval-buffer including (package-install 'flycheck), and I keep getting this message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your package archive index appears to be outdated.  Please run `M-x package-refresh-contents` and try again.

---

Besides please note that Flycheck only supports GNU Emacs.  Use with Aquamacs at your own risk.

Comment: Nice! Thanks -- I thought I had updated the index, but apparently not. So far it seems to work ok with Aquamacs.